# глобальные переменные и передача аргументов в си

Tags: c, argv

как сделать доступными аргументы  функции main всей программе на **чистом** **си**? Может есть какие то библиотеки для этого?

то есть

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    myfunc();
}

int myfunc()
{
    printf("%d %s", argc, argv[1]);
}
```

так делать не хочется

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    myfunc(argc, argv);
}

int myfunc(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d %s", argc, argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: а что мешает сделать глобальные переменные и просто скопировать в них argc и argv ?

Comment: такая идея была, но может есть более элегантное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать соответствующие глобальные переменные и инициализировать их в самом начале функции `main()` переданными ей аргументами. Это - если **чистый C**.

```
int Argc;
const char ** Argv;


void test()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n",i,Argv[i]);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Argc = argc;
    Argv = argv;

    test();

}
```

Но можно, если не подходить так строго к делу, посмотреть документацию по конкретному компилятору - как правило, имеются некоторые глобальные переменные, хранящие эти аргументы...

Answer (score 1):

Параметры явно должны как-то использоваться. Иначе в них нет смысла.
Дабы не изобретать велосипед, рекомендую ознакомиться с библиотекой [getArgs](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/contrib/com_err/getarg.c.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
int myfunc(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d %s", argc, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    myfunc(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от кода ТС?

Comment: @alexolut, тем, что я его не видел... Вероятно, открыл вопрос до того, как он был дополнен и не обновил перед ответом. В любом случае, я считаю, что так сделать правильнее. Ну и ещё, этот код скомпилируется, в отличие от того :)